# ZooKeeper - SOLR issue

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

We are using Solr 4.2.1 and ZooKeeper 3.4.5 and there are 2 Solr servers. 
Solr is reporting **"No registered leader was found"** and **"WARNING ZkStateReader ZooKeeper watch triggered,​ but Solr cannot talk to ZK"**. 
ZooKeeper is reporting **"Exception when following the leader"**. 
But after restarting both, it works for some time and it reports the issue again.

Here are some additional logs from Solr:

```
SEVERE ZkController There was a problem finding the leader in
zk:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not get leader props

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No registered leader was found, collection:www-live slice:shard1

SEVERE: shard update error StdNode: http://10.23.3.47:8983/solr/www-live/:org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server refused connection at: http://10.23.3.47:8983/solr/www-live

SEVERE: Recovery failed - trying again... (5) core=www-live
```

From ZooKeeper

```
 2016-01-14 11:25:08,423 [myid:1] - WARN  [QuorumPeer[myid=1]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:Follower@89] - Exception when following the leader
    java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
        at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readInt(BinaryInputArchive.java:63)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPacket.deserialize(QuorumPacket.java:83)
        at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readRecord(BinaryInputArchive.java:108)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner.readPacket(Learner.java:152)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Follower.followLeader(Follower.java:85)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:740)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: @JoeG, no I couldn't find any solution. But I have upgraded the solr to 5 and that stopped this issue completely. BTW, I had 2 solr servers and still have 2. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

How many zookeepers you have?

It must be on odd numbers for leader election. If it is on even number, please update it to odd number and try again.

> Three ZooKeeper servers is the minimum recommended size for an
>   ensemble, and we also recommend that they run on separate machines.
>
> For reliable ZooKeeper service, you should deploy ZooKeeper in a
>   cluster known as an ensemble. As long as a majority of the ensemble
>   are up, the service will be available. Because Zookeeper requires a
>   majority, it is best to use an odd number of machines. For example,
>   with four machines ZooKeeper can only handle the failure of a single
>   machine; if two machines fail, the remaining two machines do not
>   constitute a majority. However, with five machines ZooKeeper can
>   handle the failure of two machines.

http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html